# How to create mirror effect in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, sklightnode

Assume we have a SKLightNode, and another SKSpriteNode as a mirror in some distance to the SKLightNode. How do I make the mirror reflect the light from SKLightNode?

Comment: I do not think that the light node is that advance,  you will need to create a new light node at the point of reflection

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was thinking about make it this way too. There really no better way to implement this?